# Name for prime numbers with only prime digits?

Tags: prime-numbers

I'm wondering, is there a name for a prime number where all digits are also prime?

Some examples: 37, 53, 3253, 5573, 23753.

I've been calling them 'double primes', but I doubt that's the correct term (if there is any).

Comment: They aren't interesting enough to deserve a name.

Comment: [They don't have a name, but they're one of the Smarandache sequences...](http://oeis.org/A019546)

Comment: Uhm -- choosing a decimal representation is a rather arbitrary choice, which makes me think that this is not a very interesting property.

Comment: Here's [a link about them](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/news/2002-04-09/primeprimes/) at MathWorld, but no specific name for them.

Comment: Why not call them "prime numbers with only prime digits"?

Comment: Could call them "the 2357 primes"

Comment: Thanks for the MathWorld link. It explains why they don't have a name, since they are only "of interest to recreational mathematicians". I'm not a mathematician, so I find them interesting mainly for their "aesthetical" and "conceptual" appeal. :) Although, for "aesthetics", also including digits 0 and 1 makes more interesting numbers, I think.

Comment: let's call them oddacious primes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From GEdgar so we have an answer:

Why not call them "prime numbers with only prime digits"?

Answer (score 2):

Chris Caldwell in his [Prime Pages](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/PrimeDigitPrime.html) calls them "prime-digit primes."